# arm-none-eabi-ld with -z muldefs, symbol priority

Tags: linker, linker-scripts, linker-flags

I am using arm-none-eabi-ld to link a bunch of object files for a very specific embedded architecture (The Gameboy Advance, to be specific) - I have to reference a bunch of already defined symbols, in order to achieve that I am linking against a script that defines those (For example integer division, but things like structures / arrays of structures are in there as well)

For my purpose there exists a linker script that already predefines a bunch of those symbols and can be used as some sort of "shared linker script" in order to build and integrate different projects into another. The problem is, it also defines a bunch of symbols that I want to redefine in source files. To take a practical example:

The linker script defines `pokemon_front_sprites` (which is an array of type `void*`) - but I also define `pokemon_front_sprites` - So I decided to compile with `-z muldefs` in order to have that out of the way. It gets problematic of course if the two symbols point to different data.

My question is now as follows: Can I tell ld to prefer my symbols over the predefined ones? Can I somehow assign a priority when linking with `-T <script>`?

Comment: not sure if I understand correctly what you want, but assuming you want to define a symbol in the linker script if and only if it's not already defined elsewhere, `PROVIDE()` should allow that.

So if you have `pokemon_front_sprites = ...` currently, change that to `PROVIDE(pokemon_front_sprites = ...`

Comment: yes, yes I think that is it, thanks a bunch